# Does extra space slow down the processor?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, whitespace, unset

After learning [how to "correctly" unset a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720841/accessing-a-xml-node-directly-via-a-key), I noticed that using PHP's unset() function leaves the tabs and spaces behind. So now I have this big chunk of white space in between nodes at times. I'm wondering if PHP iterates through blank spaces/returns/tabs and whether it would eventually slow down the system.

I'm also asking whether there's an easy to remove the space unset leaves behind?

Thanks,
Ryan

**ADDED NOTE:**

This is how I removed the whitespaces after unsetting a node and it worked for me.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load($xmlPath);
$dom->save($xmlPath);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wether it slows down the process: probably to little to care about.

And simpleXML is just that, simple. If you require a 'pretty' output, DOM is your friend:

```
<?php
$xml = '
<xml>
        <node>foo </node>
        <other>bar</other>
</xml>';
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
unset($x->other);
echo $x->asXML();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->documentElement->removeChild($dom->documentElement->lastChild);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Replaced "proper" with "pretty" to avoid any misunderstanding about the properness of a "messy" XML document.

Comment: Is this the equivalent of unset?
$dom->documentElement->removeChild($dom->documentElement->lastChild);

Can I ommit this line if I just want to format the output?
Thanks, Ryan

Comment: Yes, that line was just to make a random DOM-manipulation, and can easily be omitted. If you want to format the output of SimpleXML, it it not uncommon just to `import` the result into DOM & call the `saveXML` to have some pretty formatting.

Comment: I got this error when trying the above mentioned approach:
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1

In my research I found this http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996 but I'm running 2.7.6, so I'm not sure if this still applies.

Comment: I did not say `import` for nothing ;). Try to use the function here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php If that doesn't work, post / pastebin some actual code you're trying.

Comment: OK :). Here's what I did and I'm not getting any errors now, but the document still has whitespace: $dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument; $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; $dom->formatOutput = true; $dom->saveXML();

Comment: You have to set `preserveWhiteSpace` to false & `formatOutput` to true _before_ loading the XML into it.

Comment: OK, got it working. See working code up top. Is that the right way to do it? Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace in XML is TextNodes, e.g.

```
<foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

is really

```
<foo><- whitespace node
    -><bar>baz</bar><- whitespace node
-></foo>
```

If you remove the `<bar>` node, you get

```
<foo><- whitespace node
    -><- whitespace node
-></foo>
```

I think SimpleXml wont allow you to access the Text nodes easily (maybe via XPath) but DOM does. See [Wrikken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722083/does-extra-space-slow-down-the-processor/3722187#3722187) for details. Now that you know that whitespace is a node, you can also imagine that parsing it into a node takes up some cpu cycles. However, I'd say the speed impact is negliglible. When in doubt, do a benchmark with some real world data.

---

**EDIT:** Proof that whitespace is really nodes

```
$xml = <<< XML
<foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
foreach($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node);
}
```

gives

```
object(DOMText)#4 (0) {}
object(DOMElement)#6 (0) {}
object(DOMText)#4 (0) {}
```

Comment: You're not implying that whitespace is a tag ?! ;-)  Also, Libxml can distinguish whitespace nodes from text, in fact XMLReader has 2 types of whitespace.

Comment: XPath would of course be `//text()[normalize-space()='']`, but those will be removed on loading if preserveWhiteSpace is false.

Comment: @Robin: I think Gordon meant they're actual nodes.

Comment: @Robin The `<whitespace>` wasn't meant to imply tag, but just that there is a node between the tags. Sorry if that was misleading. Changed it to a hopefully less ambigous marker.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually [Libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) that does the XML parsing, whitespace is read by the parser the same as every other character in the input stream (or file).  Most of the PHP xml APIs use Libxml under the hood (XmlReader, XmlWriter, SimpleXml Xslt, Dom...) - some of them give you access to whitespace (e.g. Dom, XmlReader), some don't (e.g. SimpleXML)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answers to the questions asked:

> I'm wondering if PHP iterates through
>   blank spaces/returns/tabs and whether
>   it would eventually slow down the
>   system.

No, PHP (or libxml) doesn't really iterate over it. Having more whitespace *theorically* slows down the system, although it's so small it can't be measured directly. You could test that by yourself by removing *all* whitespace from your XML. It wouldn't make it faster.

> I'm also asking whether there's an
>   easy to remove the space unset leaves
>   behind?

No *easy* way I'm afraid. You can import your SimpleXML stuff to DOM and use `formatOutput` to completely remodel the whitespace, as suggested in another answer, or you can use a third party library that will do it for you, but you won't find an easy, built-in way to do that.